# how mount previous ubuntu installation?

Tags: mount, xubuntu, filesystem

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and upgraded it to 22.04.  Unfortunately I created an unnecessary /usr mount point.  I would like to move the /usr into /.   To do this I've been told to boot off of new media (my DVD) and mount both filesystems.

I can boot from the Ubuntu 20.04 DVD and it has GParted showing

```
    /dev/nvme0n1    476.94 GiB
    /dev/sda        5.46 TiB
```

I found I can mount my 'discovered' installation files using the following command.

sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/SSD1
**  SSD1 must be created beforehand.

However everything seems to be READ-ONLY.  I can't even write to an inserted thumb drive.

How do I mount my previously installed 22.04 filesystem so that I can perform operations on it.  Also I need to edit /etc/fstab.

Comment: Make a few dirs under /mnt, and mount the partitions you want, then just copy what you want to/from them.  A more clever way: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/access-to-original-contents-of-mount-point